# Absolute value of complex number in polar form

Tags: linear-algebra, complex-numbers

$\displaystyle\left|\left(i^3 - \sqrt3\right)\cdot\left(\cos\frac\pi 7+i\sin\frac\pi 7\right)\right|$

I'm not sure how should I start doing this. Am I supposed to take real and imaginary parts of $\left(i^3 - \sqrt3\right)$ and $\left(\cos\frac\pi 7+i\sin\frac\pi 7\right)$ separately and then find absolute value?

Comment: Hint: the absolute value (or modulus) of a product is the product of the factor's absolute values. $\forall\theta\in\mathbb R,\ \cos^2\theta+\sin^2\theta=1$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that $i^3-\sqrt 3 =-2(\frac{\sqrt 3}{2}+i\frac{1}{2})=2(\cos\frac{\pi}{6}+i\sin\frac{\pi}{6})$

$x=i^3-\sqrt 3 =-2(\cos\frac{\pi}{6}+i\sin\frac{\pi}{6})=2e^{i\frac{\pi}{6}}$
$y=\cos\frac{\pi}{7}+i\sin\frac{\pi}{7}=e^{i\frac{\pi}{7}}$

$|xy|=2|e^{i(\frac{\pi}{6}+ \frac{\pi}{7})}|=2$

Comment: How did you get −2(cosπ/6+isinπ/6)?

Comment: Updated to explain:-)

Comment: Could you please explain how did u get pi/6?

Comment: Please refer to https://www.mathsisfun.com/geometry/unit-circle.html. These are numbers we should remember.